# Print an item in a list in a color based on the item

Tags: python, list, dictionary, colorama

I've written a script for a very clunky version of minesweeper.

The player selects the square they want to reveal based on co-ordinates (like in chess) and the board is updated with the values showing how many mines are in the squares around the chosen co-ordinates. The player can also flag where they think a mine is, which shows up as an "f".

[image: How the player board looks after the player has selected a few squares]

Unfortunately this is unreadable which makes it very slow going. So I was hoping to update the code with some colour, where all "2"s are printed in blue, all "3"s in red etc. I have all the components; I've downloaded colorama but I can't get it to work. I'm stuck with the rest.

Code that prints the initial empty grid:

```
difficulty_dictionaries = {
    1 : {
        "difficulty": "Beginner",
        "x_axis": 8, 
        "y_axis": 8, 
        "mine_no": 10
    },
    2 : {
        "difficulty": "Intermediate",
        "x_axis": 16, 
        "y_axis": 16, 
        "mine_no": 40
    },
    3 : {
        "difficulty": "Expert",
        "x_axis": 26, 
        "y_axis": 16, 
        "mine_no": 98
    }
}   

ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

def set_difficulty():
    print ("Please select difficulty level by entering either 1, 2 or 3 based on the corresponding difficulty")
    diff_input = input ("1. Beginner: \n2. Intermediate: \n3. Expert: ") 
    
    return difficulty_dictionaries[int(diff_input)]

def set_user_board():
    grid = []
    grid.append("  ")
    for set_x in range(diff_dict["x_axis"]):
        grid.append(ALPHABET[set_x])
    grid[0] = (" ".join(grid))

    del grid[1:]
    grid.append("  " + "+" + ("-+")*(diff_dict["x_axis"]))
    for set_y in range(diff_dict["y_axis"]):
        grid.append(str(set_y + 1) + " |" + (" " + "|")*diff_dict["x_axis"]) if set_y < 9 else grid.append(str(set_y + 1) + "|" + (" " + "|")*diff_dict["x_axis"])
        grid.append("  +" + ("-+")*diff_dict["x_axis"])
    return(grid)

def print_grid():
    print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, b)) for b in grid))
    return

diff_dict = set_difficulty()
grid = set_user_board()
print_grid()
```

Output:

[image: Empty player grid]

As squares are selected, the values are taken from another reference list of lists and inserted into `grid` at the relevant point.

I stole the part of the code that prints the grid from another answer on SO but I don't know how it works. I have also tried this:

```
def print_grid():
    for x in grid:
        print(*x)
    return
```

which is far more understandable. But when I try to apply the colour to the items in the list I'm encountering some problems - mostly with the `*`.

```
def print_grid():
    for x in grid:
        print(f"{Fore.RED}" + x)

    return
```

That prints an all red grid - but it's squished:
[image: Squished, red grid]

Comment: you have 2D grid and `x` means row in this grid which is list with many values - you have to convert this list to single string to add to other text. Or you have to use nested `for`-loop to display every element separately - `for y in x: print(f"{Fore.RED}" + y, end=" ")`

Comment: when you use `print(*x)` then it runs it as `print(x[0], x[1], ...)` so it prints many separated elements and `print` automatically add space between elements. You could say that every comma `,` adds `space` in output. And when you print(`f"{Fore.RED}" + x)` then you print one element and `print()` doesn't know that it needs spaces between elements - it needs to format string with spaces before using `print()`

Comment: better use nested `for`-loops  (with better names of variable) `for row in grid: for item in row: ...`  - and then you can use `if/else` to run `print()` with different colors for different items . `if item in ('+', '-', '|'): print(f"{Fore.RED}{item} ")` or `if item in ('+', '-', '|'): color = Fore.RED` and later `print(f"{color}{item} ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First explanations:

You have 2D grid and `x` can means row with many values -

When you use print(*x) then it runs it as `print(x[0], x[1], ...)` so it prints many separated elements and `print()` automatically add `space` between elements. You could say that every comma `,` adds `space` in output.

Try `print("A", "B")` and you get `"A B"` instead of `"AB"`

When you `print(f"{Fore.RED}" + x)` then you print one string (probably row converted to string) and `print()` doesn't know that it needs `spaces` between elements. You have to format this string with spaces before using `print()`

---

It would be simpler to keep `grid` as 2D grid (without converting rows to string) and use nested `for`-loops `(with better names for variables)

```py
for row in grid:
    for item in row:
        print(item, end=' ')
    print() # go to next line
```

And now you can use `if/else` to print it in different colors

```py
for row in grid:
    for item in row:
        if item in ('+', '-', '|'):  # or `if item in "+-|"`
            color = Fore.RED
        elif item in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'): # or `if item in "12345"`
            color = Fore.GREEN
        else: 
            color = Fore.WHITE
        print(f"{color}{item}", end=' ')   # I add `space` instead of `\n` as `end` 
    print() # go to next line
```

---

Minimal working example:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

grid = [
    ['+', '-', '+', '-', '+', '-', '+'],
    ['|', '1', '|', ' ', '|', ' ', '|'],
    ['+', '-', '+', '-', '+', '-', '+'],
    ['|', 'X', '|', '2', '|', ' ', '|'],
    ['+', '-', '+', '-', '+', '-', '+'],
    ['|', ' ', '|', 'O', '|', '3', '|'],
    ['+', '-', '+', '-', '+', '-', '+'],
]

# ---

# letters

print(end='   ')
for item in 'ABC':
    print(f" {Fore.WHITE + Style.BRIGHT}{item} ", end=' ')
print()

# rows 

for number, row in enumerate(grid, 1):
    
    # row's number
    
    if number % 2 == 1:
        print("  ", end='')
    else:
        print(f"{Fore.WHITE + Style.BRIGHT}{number//2} ", end='')

    # row's grid
    for item in row:
        if item in ('+', '-', '|'):  # or `if item in "+-|"`
            color = Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT
        elif item in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'): # or `if item in "12345"`
            color = Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT
        elif item in ('X', 'O'): # or `if item in "12345"`
            color = Fore.BLUE + Style.BRIGHT
        else: 
            color = Fore.WHITE + Style.BRIGHT
        print(f"{color}{item}", end=' ')   # I add space at the end of `f-string`
    print() # go to next line
```

Result (with colors) in console:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

I made more universal version which use `grid` without lines `+-+`

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import string

grid = [
    ['1', 'D', ' ', 'A', '4'],
    ['E', '2', '5', ' ', 'B'],
    ['6', 'F', '3', 'C', ' '],
]

# ---

HEIGTH = len(grid) 
WIDTH  = len(grid[0])

LETTERS = string.ascii_uppercase[:WIDTH]

# --- columns letters ---

print(end='   ')
for item in LETTERS:
    print(f' {Fore.WHITE + Style.BRIGHT}{item}  ', end='')
print()  

# --- rows ---

for number, row in enumerate(grid, 1):
    
    # top line
    
    print(f'{Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT}  +' + ' - +'*WIDTH)

    # row with data
    
    # number
    print(f'{Fore.WHITE + Style.BRIGHT}{number} ', end='')
    
    # first left line
    print(f'{Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT}| ', end='')

    # data with right line
    for item in row:
        if item in '123':
            color = Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT
        elif item in '456':
            color = Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT
        elif item in 'ABCDEF': # or `if item in "12345"`
            color = Fore.BLUE + Style.BRIGHT
        else: 
            color = Fore.WHITE + Style.BRIGHT
            
        print(f"{color}{item} {Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT}| ", end='')   # I add space at the end of `f-string`
        
    print() # go to next line

# --- last (bottom) line ---

print(f'{Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT}  +' + ' - +'*WIDTH)
```

Result (with colors) in console:

[image]